# property of roots

Tags: roots, integers

I need to prove $\gamma_n$ is an integer for any value of $n$. $\gamma_n$ is defined as $= \alpha^n + \beta^n$. $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots of equation $x^2 + mx - 1 = 0$, $m$ is an odd integer.

I tried by induction, but do not know how to prove $\gamma_n$ is an integer for $n + 1$. Can some body help

Answer (score 2):

$\gamma_{n+1} = \alpha^{n+1} + \beta^{n+1}= (\alpha^n+\beta^n)(\alpha+\beta)- \alpha\beta(\alpha^{n-1}+\beta^{n-1})= -m\gamma_n+\gamma_{n-1}$. You can use this identity to proceed at the inductive step.

Comment: Because $\alpha \beta=-1.$

Answer (score 1):

$\alpha$ and $\beta$ are algebraic integers, hence so is $\alpha^n+\beta^n$ for each $n$. Moreover, $\alpha^n+\beta^n$ is fixed by $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)/\mathbb{Q})$, so is a rational number. And if a rational number is integral over $\mathbb{Z}$, then it's an integer.

Answer (score 1):

We do the induction step, using strong induction. Suppose that $\gamma_k$ is an integer for all $k\lt n$. We show that $\gamma_n$ is an integer.
Note that
$$\alpha^n+\beta^n=(\alpha^{n-1}+\beta^{n-1})(\alpha+\beta)-\alpha\beta(\alpha^{n-2}+\beta^{n-2}).$$
But $\alpha+\beta$ and $\alpha\beta$ are integers, and the result follows.

Comment: Because $\alpha \beta=-1.$

Comment: @user254665: Yes, $\alpha+\beta=-m$ and $\alpha\beta=-1$ by the Vieta relations.

Comment: Thanks. This was very useful. Now how do I prove $\gamma_{n +1}$ and $\gamma_n$ are co-primes OR their GCD = 1?

Comment: This was very useful. Now how do I prove $\gamma_{n +1}$ and $\gamma_n$ are co-primes OR their GCD = 1?

Comment: You are welcome. The problem you are asking about can be settled by induction. Assume that $\gamma_n$ and $\gamma_{n-1}$ are relatively prime. By a version of my displayed formula, we have $\gamma_{n+1}=\gamma_n(\alpha+\beta)-\alpha\beta\gamma_{n-1}$. If $d$ divides $\gamma_{n+1}$ and $\gamma_n$, then by the formula we have $d$ divides $\alpha\beta\gamma_{n-1}$. But $\alpha\beta=-1$, so $d$ divides $\gamma_{n-1}$, contradicting the induction assumption.

Comment: The fact that $m$ is an odd integer is used here (note it was not used in the answer to the question in the OP). But we need it now, to make sure that $\alpha^0+\beta^0$, namely $2$, is relatively prime to $\alpha^1+\beta^1$, namely $-m$. That gives the base step for the induction for the relatively prime part of the problem.